# Can vector images be uploaded?

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

I would like to be able to upload a vector image (pdf, eps, svg, etc.) to my question, but SE does not seem to allow this. I know I can post a link to Dropbox or something like that, but it would be nice to have the image within the question.

Can this ability be added?

Comment: I'm guessing Imgur would need to support this first.

Comment: Just paste the SVG source into the html area of a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) and the snippet will display the SVG image,

Comment: Note that snippets are only active on some sites.